# Shared element from activity to fragment like snapchat

Tags: android, android-animation, shared-element-transition, snapchat

I am exploring share element transition from one activity to other.
I have a list of video thumbnail in one activity and in second activity i have two fragments, FragmentA and FragmentB. In FragmentB i am showing videos like snap chat. If user click on right next video will play. Now if user swipes from top and drag video to bottom, I want to make animation like snap chat where video view will shrink according to drag distance.

Please give me some hint/suggestions how can i achieve transition of element like snapchat.

Answer (score -1):

You can check this project in Github: https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel

> Draggable Panel is an Android library created to build a draggable user interface similar to the new YouTube draggable video component based on Fragments or Views.

It has the drag functionality you mentioned as seen from this image
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrLQz.gif)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16226075)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Tried to improve my answer.